# Letters are replaced by blocks on Android Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Hopefully someone has had this problem before and can share a solution.

I start an activity via startActivity(intent), the new activity launches fine, but as soon as I scroll the window, the text is replaced by blocks. Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

The activity that comes before this problematic activity is using opengl directly, maybe this has something to do with the problem?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Blocks instead of text]

EDIT: The string resources are in spanish, and some are stores in strings.xml and other are inserted programatically.

EDIT2: This is happening on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.2.2), I tested on a Galaxy S3 and Galaxy S3 mini as well and the application runs perfectly.

Comment: what kind of text are those? Are they simple strings stored in string.xml?

Comment: Where do the "letters" come from? Are they string resources or Java Strings or what?

Comment: 1) Remove all non-english strings from  strings.xml
2) In eclipse, Project Properties > Validation > XMl Syntax> Configure Workspace Settings[Right top] > XML > XML Files > Set Encoding as  ISO/Unicode (UTF-8)
3) Copy back from valid source[Where all characteres are visible properly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by disabling hardware acceleration and unchecking "Force GPU Rendering" in Settings->Developer Options.