# font is unreadable after opening app several times

Tags: android, fonts

I have a problem and sorry for my second post about this.
 After I opened my app several times the font is unreadable and looks like this: ([screenshot](https://www2.hs-augsburg.de/~vierth89/Screenshot_2013-10-15-22-55-06.png) I don't know whats going on. It's the default font of android. Who can help me? Or does anyone knows the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable Hardware Acceleration as pointed out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17068447/1096567

You can do it like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `anti-aliasing` to the font to smoothen it out, this can be added either to the element, such as:

```
p {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

or to the document if your prefer, my preference:

```
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Hope this helps.